# How to use value from sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, repeat, correlated-subquery

I have one select:

```
select
b.[FiscalPeriod],
b.[Column2],b.[Current_Value],
(
    select TOP 1 [Column3] from [table1] b2 
    where month(b.ReportingPeriod) = month(DATEADD(month,1,b2.ReportingPeriod))
      AND YEAR(b.ReportingPeriod) = YEAR(DATEADD(month,1,b2.ReportingPeriod))
      AND b.id = b2.id
) as PREV_VALUE 
FROM [table1] b
```

Now I'm doing: `(b.[Current_Value]-PREV_VALUE) as difference`

but I got error:

> Invalid column name 'PREV_VALUE'

I know that instead of `PREV_VALUE`, once again I can put sub select.
But how to avoid repeat the select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a table alias where it is defined.  In your case, the best solution is probably `outer apply`:

```
select b.[FiscalPeriod], b.[Column2],b.[Current_Value], bb.PREV_VALUE
FROM [table1] b OUTER APPLY
     (select TOP 1 [Column3] as PREV_VALUE
      from [table1] b2 
      where month(b.ReportingPeriod) = month(DATEADD(month,1,b2.ReportingPeriod)) AND
            YEAR(b.ReportingPeriod) = YEAR(DATEADD(month,1,b2.ReportingPeriod)) AND
            b.id = b2.id
      order by ???
     ) bb
```

Then you can access the value more than once in the `SELECT`.

Note:  When using `TOP` you should be using `ORDER BY`, so you should fill in the `???`.

Comment: hi, it's working without order by (it's selected only one row)

Comment: @user2207426 . . . It "works" in the sense of fetching one row.  However, if there are multiple matches, it will be returning an indeterminate row.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your query into a derived table or CTE.   Then you can treat the aliases like columns:

```
SELECT *, (Current_Value-PREV_VALUE) AS difference
FROM (
  Your current query
) q
```